# Regex Postgresql: Remove the last part of string recursively

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a string that needs to be trimmed through removing words from the end of the string. For instance, if the words `ltee.`, `company`, `co.`, or any number appear then they should be removed and it should keep removing if the "new" end of the string is still in the list.

Suppose the string `PUBLIC SCHOOL 2012 LTEE.`. First, the word `LTEE` should be removed to get `PUBLIC SCHOOL 2012` and then the number `2012` should be removed because it is a number at the end.

I attempted to get this behaviour through the following:

```
 select upper(regexp_replace(lower('PUBLIC SCHOOL 2012 LTEE.'),
                            '\d*$|\s(ltee|ltee.|company|co|co.|liability)$',
                            '','g'))
```

However, I am just getting `PUBLIC SCHOOL 2012` with the number at the end.

Is there a way to remove the number as well? How about if there is another word besides LTEE.?

For instance, the string `PUBLIC SCHOOL 2012 LTEE. CO` should become `PUBLIC SCHOOL` removing `CO`, then `LTEE.` and finally `2012`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a lookahead to match all the words (or string of digits) you want to replace at once; the lookahead asserts that between the word and the end of the line are only more of those words or strings of digits:

```
\s(\d*|ltee\.?|company|co\.?|liability)(?=(?:\s(?:\d*|ltee\.?|company|co\.?|liability))*$)
```

Sample PostgreSQL usage:

```
select upper(regexp_replace('PUBLIC SCHOOL 2012 LTEE. CO',
                            '\s(\d*|ltee\.?|company|co\.?|liability)(?=(?:\s(?:\d*|ltee\.?|company|co\.?|liability))*$)',
                            '','gi'))
```

Output:

```
PUBLIC SCHOOL
```

Note that you can supply the `i` flag to regexp_replace to make it case-insensitive, then you don't need to call `lower`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a60e012235ec1356b26ba23903433ba)